# What do we mean by curly braces in an atomic configuration?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, terminology, notation, term-symbols

What do the '{` mean in atomic configurations e.g:

```
 1s(2)2s(1)2p(2){3P}3p(1)
 1s(2)2s(2)2p(3){4S}3p(1)
```

Comment: By "we" you likely mean the authors of the text where you found this. What do they say about their notation?

Comment: All I know is that these are some excited states of Oxygen ions. I am assuming this is some form of standard representation but cannot find any explanation which is why I am asking :)

Answer (score 1):

The {3P} and {4S} are referring to triplet states. Triplet states occur when two unpaired electrons with 1/2 spin merge to give a S=1. In your case of 1s(2)2s(1)2p(2){3P}3p(1) this means the one 2s(1) electron and one 2p(2) electron share orbitals and form a triplet state. The notation should look like superscript3 P and superscript4 S but due to format complexity can be seen as {3P} and {4S}.